# Limit Behaviour of Binomial Distirbution Likelihood Function with Sterling's Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, statistics, approximation, binomial-distribution

The equation for the maximum likelihood estimator for the binomial distribution is $$\mathcal{L}(p|n,y)=\binom{n}{y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$$
For a statistical problems I am working on, I am interested in the behaviour of this function only for $p=0.5$. When we set $p=0.5$, we get
$$\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,y)=\binom{n}{y}\frac{1}{2^n}$$
My expectation would be, for $y = n/2$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,n/2)=1$$
However, when I then tried approximating $\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,n/2)$ using Stirling's approximation, I get the following derivation:
$$\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,n/2)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$$
which tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

My question is, is my derivation wrong, or:

- Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,n/2)=0$,
- Can the Sterling approximation not be applied in this context, or
- Is there some other explanation?

EDIT:
After generating some data, I think that my intuition about the limit of this function is wrong, and my derivation is correct. If that's the case - why should I expect $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{L}(0.5|n,n/2)=0$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{L}$ supposed to be?  A p.d.f.?  C.d.f.?  Random variable?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}$ is a likelihood function. E.g. seen here: https://sites.warnercnr.colostate.edu/gwhite/wp-content/uploads/sites/73/2017/04/BinomialLikelihood.pdf